# Can I modify the "move" calories for a pasta day?

Tags: ios, activity.app

I have a streak of 333+ days of hitting my move goal and I'd like to keep it.  A few days ago, according to my iPhone today, I did only 418 instead of 420 calories -- so it says I didn't meet my goal. I'd like to fudge it since I could have easily spent two extra calories and, I'm pretty sure I exercised until it said I had completed my move and exercise goals, otherwise I would have kept going.

Is there any way to go back and add in the two extra calories so that my move streak will continue? I guess it's not a huge deal but I'm kinda bummed and feeling betrayed.

iOS is version 12.3.1, watchOS is version 5.2.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you move your time zones, you can extend “today” day to be longer at the expense of losing time “tomorrow”.

I take my fitness very seriously and I am obsessed with closing all the 3 rings for 5-6 days in a week and also with the awards. I challenge myself every month. This month I pushed myself a little harder and decided to aim for perfect month award. On March 30th, I was unable to close my move ring just by 1 calorie.

But I did something that worked to close my move ring for previous day. In my opinion this works only for people living in the eastern time zone. And can be done for only 1 previous day.

I went to settings on my phone, changed my time zone from New York to San Diego. Voila!! I gained additional 3 hours for the day, I closed my move ring with that one calorie I needed the most to get my perfect month award.

But you need to wait until 00:00 AM to change back your time zone. I tried to change back my time zone immediately after closing the ring but my watch got confused. So, I left my watch on charging and changed my time zone the next morning.

Yay!! I got my first perfect month award.

I seriously will not suggest anyone to do this on a regular basis. We need to be true to ourselves to achieve our goals. I was desperate for the perfect month award, I worked hard all month long for it and did not want to lose it by just 1 calorie.

Comment: I think this is totally legit and know people that try to work out or avoid changing the time zone on their devices now when flying to keep their streaks alive. The data is only meaningful to you if it makes sense, so a month from now, which 8 hour block your exercise happened won’t matter as much as you doing the movement and keeping yourself aware of the need to move regularly.

Comment: I just did it and it worked. But, I will add a couple of observations:  I edited the time to a time before I started the last workout (after turning off “set automatically” in date & time). Just after doing it, it appeared that everything was alright, but after one minute no calorie was being registered. I restarted both the phone and the watch, then I could do the 2 minutes workout. Finally I set the time back to normal and restarted everything. iOS 14.7.1, WatchOS 7.6.1.

Answer (score 3):

You could change the date of your iPhone/Apple Watch to that day and then burn 2 calories with an activity of your choosing. After this change the date back.

Another option is to record a new activity on the Health app. Go to the app, choose Activity and then choose "Active Energy", then press the Plus sign and insert the Date and the burned calories.

Comment: I tried both of these and they didn't seem to work for me.  Changing the date seemed like a sure winner but instead the watch just got confused.

Comment: By my experience after doing this the Watch/Activity app will eventually sort themselves out. It could take some time however.

Comment: I changed the time in “date and time” and it worked, but only  **after** I restarted both the watch and the iPhone. See my comment in @Sujani’s answer.

Comment: About this suggestion of manually adding the data to the health app, it was the first thing I did, it registers the calories in the day, but it had no impact on the medals. By only doing it I would loose my move streak.

Answer (score 3):

- No you can’t add calories that didn’t get tracked.
- No you can’t change the goal after the fact.
- You can change the move goal for the current day without jailbreaking or tampering with the data store.
- I’ve heard of people extending today by making a time zone adjustment.
- I’ve had the sum be calculated wrong for workouts where I had 4 20+ minute workouts and still my move ring wasn’t closing for a reason I could not understand or fix

Without manipulating your time zone settings, one pragmatic way to avoid needing to redefine things is to set a daily alarm - 10 pm or another such time when you "Do or Die" and close all the rings you need since trying to "fake out the move goal" by lowering it late in the day doesn't seem to work when I've had people try it. I just miss my goal after trying once with the original watch to dial back the goal one day I didn’t think I could make it.

For completionists, the watch follows time zone changes so you can both adjust your goal for today and then extend “today” at the expense of the following one in many cases if you are [careful about managing time zones changes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/417903/5472).

Answer (score 0):

You can always go on the Health app on your iPhone. Active energy, in the top right corner you can Add data and just add on the 2 extra calories.

Comment: Does this work a day or three after the day in question?

Comment: Wow.  I wonder if this is new.  To clarify, iPhone => Health => Browse (lower right corner).  Then "Active Energy" and Add Data.  I've done this type of thing for Sleep but never tried it for Active Energy.